# Redirect 301 not working after first redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I'm using the following in my .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
Redirect 301 top_users.php http://example.com/top-users
RewriteRule ^top-users/?$ top_users.php

Redirect 301 register.php http://example.com/register
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php

Redirect 301 register.php?log=1 http://example.com/login
RewriteRule ^login/?$ register.php?log=1
```

The top users page seems to be working fine, and it works fine if i go straight to /login or /register, but the redirect isn't working. I've tried adding a forward slash before the redirect page name but it gives me the wrong path and says it cannot be found.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

UPDATE:

The final code i used was as below, thanks to Jon Lin for the help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /top-users(/|$|\ )
RewriteRule ^top-users(/|$|\ ) top_users.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /top_users\.php
RewriteRule ^top_users\.php$ http://example.com/top-users/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /register(/|$|\ )
RewriteRule ^register(/|$|\ ) register.php [L]

# check if request for register.php does not include log=1 in query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /register\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !log=1
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ http://example.com/register/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /login(/|$|\ )
RewriteRule ^login(/|$|\ ) register.php?log=1 [L,QSA]

# check if request for register.php includes log=1 in query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /register\.php
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ http://example.com/login/? [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are causing a redirect loop. You should be redirecting when the original request is for the php file, and rewriting when the original request is for the nicer looking URI:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /top-users(/|$|\ )
RewriteRule ^top-users top-users.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /top-users\.php
RewriteRule ^top-users\.php$ http://example.com/top-users/ [R=301]

etc...
```

For the other 2 you need to match against query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /register(/|$|\ )
RewriteRule ^register register.php [L]

# check if request for register.php does not include log=1 in query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /register\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !log=1
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ http://example.com/register/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /login(/|$|\ )
RewriteRule ^login register.php?log=1 [L,QSA]

# check if request for register.php includes log=1 in query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /register\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)log=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^register\.php$ http://example.com/login/ [R=301]
```

You cannot match against the query string in a `Redirect` or `RewriteRule`. You have to do it using a `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: I've tried this way and it just redirects as noted in my previous comments. Is there something i could have stopping it from working properly?

Comment: @johnwilliams sorry, misread your question. I edited my answer

Comment: Getting somewhere now. visiting register.php redirects fine to /register/, but throws a 404 on register with no forward slash for some reason? Visiting register.php?log=1 redirects to login/?log=1 when I'd like it to just be /login/, but it's half way there. top_users.php still returns top_users.php. visiting '/login/' and '/register/' work fine but 'top-users/' is a 404. I never thought it'd be this complicated. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just add question marks after the slashes to indicate that they are optional

Comment: If I add question marks it either stops the redirect from register.php to /register/ or /register (without forward slash) does not work? I've tried for a while to get to grips with regex to see whats going on but learning at a really slow pace.

Comment: Then try `(/|$|\ )`, which means: either a `/` or the end of the match or a space. The Rule matches need to be changed accordingly. This is what happens when you have "register" and "register.php", one being a subset of another.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the mod_rewrite flags? You could edit every two lines into one in the following manner

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^top-users(/?)$ top_users.php [L,QSA,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

`QSA`stands for Query String Append, for any GET parameters and with `R=301` you replace the preceding line of each of your rules.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to the whole .htaccess, I've placed your code and tried it and it gives me a 404 pointing to `example.com/home/mysite/public_html/top_users.php`. Do i need to make further edits to your code or is there something else going wrong?

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` in your root dir? Would that be `public_html`?

Comment: I've just edited the code above, your `.htaccess` should lokk something like this

Comment: It's till not working for me and redirecting the same way as before...it's driving me insane.